# Python 3 - list inside dictionary, if list contains a 3rd item do this

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python so sorry if this is a silly question. I have looked around but any example i have found i havnt been able to apply to my goal.

I have a dictionary with lists inside.

```
myDict = {'list1': ['item1', 'item2'], 'list2': ['item1', 'item2', 
'item3']}
```

I am taking user input to decide which list to read. I want to print something with each item in the list but my lists do not contain the same amount of items so i think i need an if statement to say something like:
if list selected has 3 items do this?

Comment: `if list selected has 3 items do this?` Can you provide a **[mcve]** of what you are trying to achieve? You have defined an input dictionary but it's not clear what you mean by `I want to print something with each item in the list but..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print something with each element of your dictionary you can do

```
for k, v in myDict.items():
    for x in v:
        print(x)
```

This way you don't need to worry about the size.

Now, if you care about finding a specific list, i.e. the one with 3 elements, you can do:

```
if len(myDict[chosen_list])>2:
   print('found list with more than 2 items')
```